# Sidebar showing file structure in Overleaf suddenly disappeared, how to recover?

Tags: overleaf

Can't believe I can't find anyone else who has had this problem.

I'm  using Overleaf for a project and at some point closed the file structure window to get more writing space. Well, now I can't find a way to get it back. I've tried refreshing, I've tried several different browsers, all to no avail. After researching, it seems people who have this problem with the *preview* bar have had success just clicking the area where the expansion should go, but that doesn't work for the file structure sidebar.

Here's a screenshot of what my workspace looks like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: click on "Project" in the top left

Comment: Bizarrely, this didn't work for me (just refreshed the page) until I tried a different browser...weird. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, clicking on "Project" on the top left as @ArTourter said shoud _always_ work

Comment: I just ran into the same issue after opening Overleaf for the first time in several weeks. Clicking on "Project" worked for me. I didn't do it at first because I thought it would launch a new project. Not intuitive at all.